# "¿Qué te interesa?" or "¿Qué te interesan?"

Tags: gramática

To ask somebody about their interests in Spanish I understand you should say:

> ¿Qué te interesa?

Would it ever be appropriate to say:

> ¿Qué te interesan?

As if I was to ask such a general question in English I would usually expect multiple interests to be listed not just one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second question is not grammatically correct, the verb is plural and the subject singular. To ask someone about their interests the correct question would be:

> ¿Cuáles son tus intereses?

Comment: Are you saying _te_ is the subject? So _¿Qué os interesan?_ would be grammatically correct? I thought _te_ was the object in this question.

Comment: +1 because you posted first. :D

Comment: The subject in the sentence is _qué_, a pronoun which is inherently singular, so the verb must be in singular. _¿Qué os interesan?_ would be grammatically INCORRECT for the very same reason. Correct alternatives would be _¿Qué os interesa?_ or _¿Qué cosas os interesan?_ In this last case, _qué_ is no longer a pronoun but an adjective modifying the noun _cosas_ --it should be in its plural form, but the adjective _qué_ is invariant.

Comment: @Auron  You're totally right. I'm sorry, my mistake. I'm going to delete my comment.

Comment: @Auron, that helps a lot. Thanks! Everybody, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think *¿Qué te interesan?* is a valid question if you meant to ask "*What are your interests?*"

I'd rather say:

> ¿*Cuáles son tus intereses?*

Comment: +1 u posted first muahahah

Comment: +1 because we where probably answering at the same time :)

Comment: Ahahah :D Laura, you were the first, trust me. :)

Answer (score 4):

The good way to say this would be:

> ¿Qué te interesa?

Interesan is used in other contexts, e.g.,

> Tengo cuatro gatitos y nosé qué hacer con ellos. ¿Te interesan [Interesan is making reference to the kittens!]?

Another way to say this would be:

> ¿Cuáles son tus intereses?

Comment: _Interesan_ because there is more than one kitten?

Comment: Exactly. **Interesan** is for plural in both ways, for instance: `Ellos se interesan por ella` (THEY are interested in her) `A él le interesan las chicas` (HE is interested in them)

Comment: +1 for the extended information and for editing, How do you put de yellow thing?

Comment: Use the quote tool on the formatting palette. Or just type '>' before the statement that you want to quote :-)

Answer (score 1):

To say "What interests you?", use

> ¿Qué te interesa?

But to say "What are your interests?", use

> ¿Cuáles son tus intereses?

Even in English there is the distinction.  It depends on what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

To add to other answers: Another possible way of making the second question correct, would be

> ¿Qué cosas te interesan?